How can I mimic a touch to my phone's screen
Hi I want to build a circuit that can mimic a finger touching a screen. I need to be able to have my device sit on my phone screen and send touch events through the touch screen (which I assume is capacitive) without any moving mechanical parts. I was hoping to be able to do this with a PCB and some copper pads. I would then add a transistor and a small capacitor to change the capacitance between the pads. I started just playing around with some ceramic capacitors of various valves touching them to be phones screen in developer mode. I can't get any response. Would anyone be able to provide more insight as to how to mimic a finger. I was assuming a real touch event was just modifying the relative dielectric of between two conductors embedded in the touch screen. Any insight about how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Does this answer your question? Are electric linear solenoids the best option to push a capacitive screen button on a smartphone?

How could hovering some separate capacitors without electrical connection to the phone screen change the relative capacitance of the two conductors in the touch screen?

You need a conductive surface in direct contact with the glass,
eg: conductive rubber. or possibly copper tape stuck to the glass.
any air gap will hurt performance.
use a small MOSFET like 2N7000 to gate the conductive pad to phone ground (like the charging port) or to a larger conductive pad on the back of the phone.

Hi Jasen, thanks for your suggestion. I made this video showing how I am experimenting (at 0:44 I meant to say changing capacitance). I don't think it has to be grounded because I can touch it with an isolated spoon and it triggers. I think it is the self capacitance. What are your thoughts? https://youtu.be/UlpBKYwZQKk

The phone being a small device with no ground connection cannot measure the self capacitance of large objects directly, it can only infer it from how much loading they put on the screen sensors.  the techniques I describe are ways to make the simulated touch appear to have a greater self capacitance while being a compact device.
